# Apache WebDAV Configuration - Map Directory As Subdirectory

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, webdav

In Apache, how do I map a directory as a subdirectory in another directory?

e.g. I have two directories:

```
/var/www/aaa
/var/www/bbb
```

Directory `/bbb` should be also available in `/aaa/bbb`.

I tried:

```
Alias "/aaa/bbb" "/var/www/bbb"
<Directory "/var/www/bbb">
Dav on
Options Indexes
</Directory

<Directory "/var/www/aaa">
Dav on
Options Indexes
</Directory
```

This works in so far as I can access `/aaa/bbb` directly. But if I open `/aaa`, the "virtual" subdirectory `/aaa/bbb` will not be shown.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried `Alias "/aaa/bbb" "/var/www/bbb"`[...] This works in so far as I can access `/aaa/bbb` directly. But if I open `/aaa`, the "virtual" subdirectory `/aaa/bbb` will not be shown.

The `Alias` command simply maps a given URL (`/aaa/bbb`) to a file system path (`/var/www/bbb`). Any URL (e.g. literally `/nonsense/url`) could be mapped to `/var/www/bbb` in Apache with `Alias`. The URL has no relation to the directory structure on your drive (which is what you are seeing when you access `/aaa` directly).

The simple solution to your issue is to create a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) (or similar) in `/aaa` to `/bbb`. It's worth noting that this is done in your OS, not Apache. Assuming Apache is configured correctly, `/bbb` should be displayed as a normal directory link when accessing `/aaa`.

Comment: Thanks. I hoped there is an apache-only solution. I tried symbolic links but unfortunately not all WebDAV Clients we use support them :-/